# Execute a stored procedure and get single out parameter in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, stored-procedures, jpa-2.0

Suppose I have a simple MS SQL Server procedure that takes 2 int arguments and returns the sum

```
CREATE PROC add_them 
    @param1 int,
    @param2 int,
    @result int OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN   
    SET @result = @param1 + @param2;
END
```

**Can I call this procedure from Hibernate (version 4.3.1)?**

So far I used a `session.createSQLQuery("exec add_them :param1, :param2")` approach setting the params later on and executing it with `query.list()`..

But this doesn't work, since the procedure doesn't return a set, but a single out value.

So, can I call this procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
Query addItemQuery=session.createSQLQuery("exec add_them :param1, :param2");
addItemQuery.setInteger("param1", 1);
addItemQuery.setInteger("param2", 2);
objArrList=addItemQuery.list();
```

Comment: this is essentially what I have described to have already tried.. I get a `SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 24000
The executeQuery method must return a result set.
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet` error

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try this:

```
Query addItemQuery=session.createSQLQuery("exec add_them :param1, :param2");
.SetParameter("param1", param1)
.SetParameter("param2", 2);
.list<int>();
```